# Java Array Element Type

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I want to know what kinds of reference can be array elements.

I know that there're primitive types like:

```
String[] strs = new String[5];
```

But there is no

```
List<String>[] stringList;
```

However, when I new a class, there is

```
Class Student{
     String name;
     List<String> courses;
}

Student[] students = new Student[5];
```

It says "The element type of an array may be any type, whether primitive or reference."

I think Student is reference and List<> is also reference. What's the difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: "But there is no `List<String>[] stringList;`" There is, if you declare and create it.

Comment: There is no difference. Simple type arrays is one kind; arrays of Object is another kind. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Also note that `String` is not a primitive type. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2

Answer (score 1):

Anything can go in an array. Primitives, other arrays, or lists.

Any of the following are legitimate declarations:

```
int[] intArray;
int[][] arrayOfIntArrays;
List <String> stringList;
List <String[]> stringArrayList; 
List <List<String[]>> badIdea; //list of a list of string arrays
List<String>[] array of a list of strings
```

etc.

An array is a subclass of `Object`. There is nothing special about it except that java gave it some unique syntax. Otherwise, it's just like anything else you run into in java.

Comment: But when I use " List<String> l = new List<>()[5] "  There's an error. How can I create a new array of a list of strings

Comment: List <String[]> stringArrayList = new ArrayList <> (); for (int i = 0; i < stringArrayList.size(); i++ ) { stringArrayList.add (new String[ 10 ]; ) }

Comment: How can I create an array of a list of strings like your last code "List<String>[] "  ?

Comment: List<String>[] listOfArrays = new List<String>[5]; should work.

Comment: Also -- making an array of lists or a list of arrays probably means you're doing something wrong. I'm helping with the syntax, but you should really consider what you're doing and whether it makes the most sense. :)